# Clojure: I am trying to use 'some' instead of 'doseq' but I am not really sure how to use it

Tags: clojure

How to replace the "doseq" with "some" in this scenario. I am new to clojure.

```
(def handle (atom ()))
    ;; #'user/players
    ;; conjoin a keyword into that list
    (swap! handlers conj [:report "handles"])
    ;;=> ([:report "handles"])
    ;; conjoin a second keyword into the list
    (swap! handlers conj [:demo "handles2"])
    ;;=> ([:demo "handles2"] [:report "handle"])
    (doseq [[a b] @handlers] (println a "--" b))
     ;;=> :demo -- handles2
    ;;=> :report -- handles
```

Comment: I've only coded in Clojure and not ClojureScript, but based on syntax, `#((= :report %) @ handlers ...)` will start your anon fn as `true` which is not a valid fn call. I guess that you're mostly right, except it's `(some #(= :report %) @handlers)` followed by moving (fn-handle event) into the `if` body.

Comment: @AaronBell: Sorry didn't get your comment, can you please explain it with example, if possible, thanks

Comment: Please update your question with sample & output.  Also, try to simplify the example to the bare minimum.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlanThompson: I have updated the question, please help me with that

Comment: `doseq` and `some` do fundamentally different things, you can't replace one with the other.

Comment: `some` takes a predicate function and a collection. You are conjing a collection in your atom but have no conditional, so what predicate would you be using? Without more detail your question really doesn't make any sense. Even with your edit, why are you using an atom in what is supposed to be a *minimal code sample*? Why do you have to build it up with conj? As far as I can tell you could have just written `(def foo [:report "whatever" :demo "whatever-else"])` and then `(doseq [[a b] foo] (println a "--" b))`. If the details matter please explain the relevance or remove them.

Comment: You have `(def handle ...)` but then you reference something called `handlers` in your `(swap! ...)` calls. Should those be e.g `(swap! handle conj [:report "handles"])`, or perhaps the def should be `(def handlers (atom ()))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clojure docs for [doseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) and [some](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some_q) are loaded with examples that can help you figure out what to use and how to use it.

There are several things I don't know about your situation, but maybe I can help with these examples.

---

### [some](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq)

Detects if something exists  based on a condition. Returns the result of the predicate, if the predicate returns truthy.

Takes a *predicate* and a *collection*

Predicate examples:

```
#(= 2 %) ; Equals 2
(fn [val] (= val "user3438838")) ; equals your username
```

Collection examples:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
["user3438838" "programs" "in" "Clojure"]
```

Let's evaluate the combinations of these:

```
(some #(= 2 %) [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]) ; => true
(some #(= 2 %) ["user3438838" "programs" "in" "Clojure"]) ; => nil
(some (fn [val] (= val "user3438838")) [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]) ; => nil
(some (fn [val] (= val "user3438838")) ["user3438838" "programs" "in" "Clojure"]) => true
```

---

### [doseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq)

Implement an expression for all elements of a sequence, for side effects. This is the first function I looked for when coming from JS, but it's usually not the right thing (it doesn't take advantage of lazily evaluating, decreasing performance). Generally want to apply a recursive expression, like `loop` with `recur`, but `doseq` may make sense here.

We'll take the same approach as with `some`

`doseq` takes (a) *sequence*(s) and and *expression* that ostensibly uses each element of the sequence.

Sequence examples:

```
[x ["user3438838" "programs" "in" "Clojure"]]
[x [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]]

; Note: Can use multiple [x (range 10) y (range 10 20)]
```

Body expression examples:

```
(println x)
(println (str "The number/word is: " x))
```

And now we'll combine these:

```
(doseq [x ["user3438838" "programs" "in" "Clojure"]] (println x)) ; Prints "user3438838\nprograms\nin\nClojure"
(doseq [x ["user3438838" "programs" "in" "Clojure"]] (println (str "The number/word is: " x))) ; Prints "The word is: user3438838 ..." 
(doseq [x [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]] (println x)) ; Prints "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8
(doseq [x [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]] (println (str "The number/word is: " x))) ; Prints "The number/word is: 1 ..."
```

---

Hope this helps you understand the two.

And if you're new, I think the go-to book for learning Clojure is [Daniel Higginbotham's (2015) *Clojure for the Brave and True*](https://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/) where he describes [some](https://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/#filter_and_some) (and not `doseq` b/c you generally want to use lazily/recursively evaluated expressions).